# find class on table header of checkbox clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find class on table header of correspoding checkbox clicked in td in html table.Actually two header rows are present.Please help me out to write js code .

```
 <table runat="server" border="1" width="100%">
   <tr ><th colspan="4">Aetna cOmmercial</th></tr>
        <tr class="row0">
        <th class=colindex0 >Alta</th>
        <th class=colindex1>Hplan</th>
        <th class=colindex2 >Hosp</th>
        <th class=colindex3 >Other</th>

        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
        <td class="gvclass1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="true" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" /></td>
         <td class="gvclass1">
             <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" /></td>
         <tr></table>
```

Comment: Hi, hope we can help. What have you done so far?

Comment: make a fiddle whatever you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class for each checkbox and then you could find the closest td index and subsequently previous tr and filter out corresponding th by that index.

Note: your html structure is invalid as the last tr is not closed properly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".chk").click(function () {
                //debugger;
                var $td = $(this).closest('td');
                var $th = $td.closest('tr').prev('tr').find('> th:eq(' + $td.index() + ')');
                console.log($th.attr('class'));
            });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

here I adjusted your code so when you click on any checkbox it displays the corresponding items in th. (you need to have jQuery)

```
<table runat="server" border="1" width="100%">
   <tr class="row0">
     <th class=colindex0>Alta</th>
     <th class=colindex1>Hplan</th>
     <th class=colindex2>Hosp</th>
     <th class=colindex3>Other</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="row1">
     <td class="gvclass1"><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked="true" /></td>
     <td class="gvclass1"><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /></td>
     <td class="gvclass1"><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" /></td>
     <td class="gvclass1"><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" /></td>
   <tr>
</table>

<script>
  $('input').click(function(){
    var arr = $("input:checkbox");
    var arrCheked = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (arr[i].checked){
        arrCheked.push($('th:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')').html());
      }
    }

    alert(arrCheked);
  });
</script>
```

I hope I have helped!